# Trigger method of different class library from another class library in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, class-library

I have a two class library
A and B. A is written in VB and B is written in C#

A has a reference of B. So that I cannot instantiate a method from B on A class library.

Now I have a scenario where if some method of B library executed then some method of A library should also be executed.
Note here I can't call method of A in B because B already is referenced in A.

I tried to delegates for this but doesn't seems to work

Here is what is have tried so far (this is code is generated from ChatGPT but doesn't work)

```cs
public delegate void MethodExecutedEventHandler();

public class ClassB
{
    public event MethodExecutedEventHandler MethodExecuted;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Method logic here...

        // Raise the event when the method is executed
        MethodExecuted?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And on a A side

```vb
Public Class ClassA
    Private WithEvents b As New ClassB()

    Private Sub OnMethodExecuted() Handles b.MethodExecuted
        ' Method logic to be executed when the method in class B is executed
    End Sub
End Class
```

`SomeMethod` of ClassB is auto-executed on every minute by job. So when `SomeMethod` method is executed I want `OnMethodExecuted` of ClassA also be executed.

Is it possible to do?

If so how can I do this?

Comment: so you have some circular dependency between A and B, right? Can you extract that into a common library that both, A and B, depend on? You can use delegates, of course. But chances are you need to rethink your class-structure.

Comment: I tried making another class library 
Can you give some example how can i achieve this approach from another class library

Comment: "SomeMethod of ClassB is autoexuted on every minute by job" - in which *instance* of ClassB though? My guess is that it's *not* the instance that's been created in ClassA.

Comment: @JonSkeet ClassB implements the IJob interface of Quartz job and auto executed on every minute. So the quartz trigger SomeMethod on every minute. I didn't post the full code here

Comment: So is Quartz creating an instance of ClassB? There's no way for *that* instance of ClassB to know about the instance created in ClassA, so therefore it doesn't have its event handler configured to call the method in ClassA. If you can change things to make Quartz use the instance of ClassB created by ClassA, that should sort the problem. (I'm not familiar with Quartz, so can't say how to do that.) It's worth noting that nothing about this disconnect is because you're using a mixture of languages or even that you're using two projects.

Comment: @JonSkeet Instance of ClassB is in a ClassA. Do you have any other alternative so that i can trigger method of ClassA from ClassB And yes i have two project one is on VB that was created about 5-6 years ago . Now i have requirement to implement scheduler so that i created a new project in c#. Do you have any idea on how to trigger ClassA method from ClassB ?

Comment: "Instance of ClassB is in a ClassA." I know there *is* an instance of ClassB in ClassA - but I strongly suspect that's *not* the instance of ClassB that Quartz is using. And yes, I know you have two projects, one in VB and one in C# - I'm saying that's not really relevant. What *is* relevant is that the instance of ClassB that executes the method (via Quartz) needs to be the instance that's configured to call the method in ClassA. It's really important that you understand that.

Comment: I think your approach is correct in principle. But if you want the method called periodically I would create a timer in the constructor of class B, unless you have some special requirements that can only be fulfilled by Quartz. And if you need to use quartz, you absolutely need to ensure that Quartz and your A-object share the same *instance*. You can use the "MakeObjectId" feature in the debugger to check if instances are identical.